# code suggestion box text not readable vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

my vscode code suggestion box is not looking good. (version 1.78.0)
how to get this fixed

[image]

I should be able to see the text easily but currently it's not readable.

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in the command palette) into your question post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your `settings.json`, it will reset line height to default

```json
"editor.suggestLineHeight": 0,
```

Comment: It worked.
Thank you so much.
I was even about to reinstall.
Really appreciate your help !